# What is hardware and software GLES 2.0 option of graphics in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, graphics, virtual, android-virtual-device

Can anyone explain to me what's the use of hardware and software GLES 2.0 option of graphics in android studio? And when to choose which option?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

From Android Studio [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration):

> When you create an Android Virtual Device (AVD) in the AVD Manager, you can specify whether the emulator should use hardware or software to emulate the GPU of the AVD. Hardware acceleration is recommended and is typically faster. However, you might need to use software acceleration if your computer uses graphics drivers that aren't compatible with the emulator.

> By default, the emulator decides whether to use hardware or software graphics acceleration based on your computer setup. If your GPU hardware and drivers are compatible, the emulator uses the GPU. Otherwise, the emulator uses software acceleration (using your computer's CPU) to simulate GPU processing.